# Slice a UIView into multiple CALayers

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How can I slice a UIView into multiple CAlayers in order to perform an animation on each slice separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't konw what you are trying to do exactly, but you could render that view into an image (1), crop multiple images out of it (2) and perform your animations on them.

(1) [Saving UIView contents in iOS 4 with real size of the images inside (i.e. scale contentes up for save)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213529/saving-uiview-contents-in-ios-4-with-real-size-of-the-images-inside-i-e-scale)

(2) [How use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect for iPhone 4 (HD)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150364/how-use-cgimagecreatewithimageinrect-for-iphone-4-hd)