# How can I maintain quality of the cropped image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have used the following code to crop an image so that it should fit into some fixed size (ex: 100*100)

```
  if(newSize.width == Thumbnail_Size) // Thumbnail_Size 100.0
  {               
      CGFloat side = width;
      if(width > height)
      {
        side = height;
      }
      CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, side, side);
      CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, croppedRect);
      newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:croppedImage];
      if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");
      return newImage ;       
  }
```

but the quality of the image is not good. Images are appearing as in the below screenshot:

[image]

I have set the imageview's contentmode as `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

What else I need to do to maintain the quality of the cropped image?

Comment: I think you ment scaling not cropping. and when scaling you will lose some clarity. I think scaling with aspect ratio would have done the trick. would you give an idea on what were the original size?

Comment: hi try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150364/how-use-cgimagecreatewithimageinrect-for-iphone-4-hd

Comment: I have even tried that. instead of imageWithCGImage method, I have used imageWithCGImage: scale: orientation: but the quality is still the same.